Software to run LLMs locally offline
I am looking for

a software that uses LLMs
the LLMs are downloaded once but then run locally
any data entered by me remains local as well
is easy to install, no messing with Python, Docker or anything
has a self-explanatory UI (may assume some LLM-specific wording like temperature, context length etc.)
model search is straight forward
is gratis
works on Windows 10

Optional:

commercial use. I eventually want that, but during the evaluation phase, personal use is ok.

I have tried:

Ollama, but it needs some kind of UI (like Openweb UI), which I struggle with for days now
AnythingLLM only has few models for selection. It's unclear which model is currently active. The concept of "workspaces" is a bit overwhelming. Opening the settings cancels the currently active chat. etc.


LM Studio
✓ uses LLMs: yes, I e.g. use Mistral Nemo Instruct 2407, Meta Llama 3 Instruct, Phi 2
✓ the LLMs are downloaded once but then run locally: yes. By default they will reside in  C:\Users\<username>\.cache\lm-studio\models
? any data entered by me remains local as well: not 100% sure
✓ is easy to install: a Windows installer, like any "normal" application
✓ has a self-explanatory UI: basically you need only 2 buttons: Search and Chat, maybe My Models to delete models. The UI has a great overview and layout.
✓ model search is straight forward: definitely. You just enter the name of a model, choose a size, download, done.
✓ is gratis: yes, but closed source.
✓ works on Windows 10: yes, I run it on Windows 10 x64.
Commercial use: no

[...] using the Services for your personal, non-commercial purposes.

Source: LM Studio terms
Some words of caution:

make sure you have a LOT of RAM. With 64 GB of PC RAM, you may barely run a 48 GB model. If you exceed RAM, it will become very slow.
models are huge. You need to be patient or have a really good Internet connection. Prepare for download over night.
models are huge. You need plenty of disk space. The few models I downloaded already take up 112 GB.

Model search and download:

Chat with the LLM:

Model management:

